# Which replacement commands to find for CartesianMap and PolarMap?

Tags: plotting, graphics, complex, compatibility

In a notebook I am studying, a few commands no longer work, namely:

- `CartesianMap[]`
- `PolarMap[]`

I assume that these commands are in the obsolete package: `` Graphics`ComplexMap` `` , but I have not been able to find that.

Are there any commands that can replace `CartesianMap` and `PolarMap`?

Comment: Just search them in the document by pressing F1, the modern version of these 2 functions are documented in [Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/ComplexMap](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/ComplexMap.html)

Comment: `ComplexMap` can be found at https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/6814/.  You need to change the `FilterOptions` call to `If[$VersionNumber >= 9, 
 FilterOptions[a_, b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]], 
 Needs["Utilities\`FilterOptions\`"]]`.  The package then works fine.  If you don't care about remaining compatible with older versions of mathematica, you can take the FilterOptions function out of the `If` statement and just assign the first part that's within the `If`.

Comment: @BillWatts Turn this to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComplexMap` can be found at https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/6814/.

You need to change the line

```
Needs["Utilities`FilterOptions`"]
```

in the package to

```
If[$VersionNumber >= 9, 
   FilterOptions[a_, b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]], 
   Needs["Utilities`FilterOptions`"]]
```

The package then works fine. If you don't care about remaining compatible with older versions of mathematica, you can take the `FilterOptions` function out of the `If` statement and just assign the first part that's within the `If`.

For future reference, most all legacy packages can be found at https://library.wolfram.com/ and then search for the one you want. They will give warning messages about being obsolete, but may still work with or without some alteration.  Be aware that they may not work at all.

Comment: I take the liberty to elaborate a bit so it's easier to understand for a beginner. Feel free to rollback if you don't like it :) .

Comment: @xzczd looks good to me. Thanks

Comment: @xzczd : ComplexMap can be found at https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/6814/. , <br/> But it seems to me a empty package , or do i miss something?

Comment: Little bit complicated to start from the obselote example commands : CartesianMap and CaresianMap into the new ones

Comment: @janhardo It's not empty. Please check it carefully.

Comment: @xzczd, i am lost with this transition to the two new commands and old package content 
 Don't know of the old commands what the input is compared with new ones

Comment: @janhardo I'm sorry, but I fail to understand your question. If you mean you still don't know how to update the package, then: 1. Open the package. 2. Find the line `Needs["Utilities\`FilterOptions\`"]` 3. Replace it with `If[$VersionNumber >= 9, 
   FilterOptions[a_, b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]], 
   Needs["Utilities\`FilterOptions\`"]]` and save.

Comment: @xzczd  its about the two commands : PolarMap and CartesianMap.
And about this package :  
Download  ComplexMap.m (4.5 KB) - Mathematica Package.
Are there any lines too find in this package?

Comment: @janhardo As mentioned above, you only need to modify the line `Needs["Utilities\`FilterOptions\`"]`. If you can't spot the line, press Ctrl+F and search.

Comment: Ok, i changed the  package  ComplexMap and get a colored picture for `CartesianMap[Sin, {-2, 2, 0.1}, {-2, 2, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 60]`
It shows the whole mapping

Comment: ![ Sin in CartesianMap old package](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pb84u5rlcu0ro5b/plaatje-catesianmap-Sin.png?dl=0)
Note: tried to show here the pic?

Comment: Compare this picture with new picture here above.
Zooming to origin for the axis, needed for the old picture

Comment: Controlling the pictures for view is another thing in MMA 
[two mapping Sin](https://www.dropbox.com/s/my5xzaocr2ndroj/plaatje-catesianmap-Sin-versie%202.png?dl=0)

Comment: So is it working for you?

Comment: @janhardo Ajust the `PlotRange` option. If you don't know how to, please check the document by pressing **F1**. Get used to reading the document by pressing **F1** is the first thing to learn when using _Mathematica_.

Comment: @ xzczd Thanks!

Comment: This set of notebooks may be of interest to you now that you have ComplexMap working.  https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/8104/

Answer (score 6):

Let me expand my comment to an answer. The compatibility info of these 2 functions is in [Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/ComplexMap](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/ComplexMap.html). You can easily find it by searching `CartesianMap`/`PolarMap` in the document by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>. As mentioned therein, you can use `ParametricPlot` for the task. Of course you don't need to modify your legacy code vastly, just define:

```
ClearAll[CartesianMap, PolarMap, picture]

Options[CartesianMap] = {Lines -> 15, PlotStyle -> None};

CartesianMap[arg__, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 picture[arg, {x, y} |-> x + I y, CartesianMap, opt]

Options[PolarMap] = {Lines -> 15, PlotStyle -> None};

PolarMap[arg__, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 picture[arg, {r, t} |-> r Exp[I t], PolarMap, opt]

tomesh = {u0, u1, du, default} |-> 
   If[du === Automatic, default, (u1 - u0)/du + 1 // Round];

picture[func_, {u0_, u1_, du_ : Automatic}, {v0_, v1_, dv_ : Automatic}, 
  map_, cmd_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ParametricPlot[ReIm@func@map[u, v], {u, u0, u1}, {v, v0, v1}, 
  Evaluate@FilterRules[{opt, Options@cmd}, Options@ParametricPlot], 
  Mesh -> ({tomesh[u0, u1, du, #], tomesh[u0, u1, du, #]} &@
     OptionValue[{opt, Options@cmd}, Lines])]

PolarMap[BesselJ[2, #] &, {0, 8}, {0, Pi/4}, Lines -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `Lines` option is the only additional option of these 2 functions in the original package:

[image]

And it's OK to pass options of `ParametricPlot` to them. Let's test OP's example in the comment below:

```
CartesianMap[Sin, {-2, 2, 0.1}, {-2, 2, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But nowadays `ParametricPlot` has done a better job in automatic `PlotRange` choosing and adaptive sampling, so the code above can be simplified to

```
CartesianMap[Sin, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, Lines -> 41]
```

The resulting graphic looks the same so I'd like to omitted it.

Comment: @ xzczd thanks
Now i must do a calculation with :
`CartesianMap[Sin, {-2, 2, 0.1}, {-2, 2, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 60]`

Comment: Don't get this new two functions working in my notebook by replacing the old two obselote functions.
What the input is for the new functions if i look at the old two obselote functions ?

Comment: @janhardo Oops, I didn't notice there exist undocumented features. Check the update.

Comment: @janhardo By "undocumented features" I mean the syntax `{-2, 2, 0.1}` and support for `PlotRange` etc. are not mentioned in [_v5.2_ document](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/StandardPackages/Graphics/ComplexMap.html).