# Complex Map Using ComplexRegionPlot

Tags: complex, regions

I am self-studying complex analysis using Dennis Zill's, *A First Course in Complex Analysis*. I'm a bit stuck on one of the exercises in Chapter 2.4, which asks us to find the image of the region shown in the figure below under the principal square root function $w=z^\frac{1}{2}$.

[image]

My naive attempt, based on the [Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexRegionPlot.html) for `ComplexRegionPlot` is:

```
region[z_] := 0 >= Re[z] >= 4 - (Im[z])^2/16 && Im[z] >= 0;
f[z_] := z^(1/2);
{ComplexRegionPlot[region[z], {z, 20}, PlotLabel -> z],
 ComplexRegionPlot[region[InverseFunction[f][z]], {z, 20}, 
  PlotLabel -> f[z]]}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

My confusion is, why am I getting two triangular regions for the image? Shouldn't the image be limited to the single triangular region in the first quadrant?

EDIT:
Upon further reflection, it appears that my function `f[z_] := z^(1/2)` is not the principal square root function. If I instead define a new function,

```
g[z_] := Sqrt[Abs[z]] E^(I Arg[z]/2)
```

then do

```
{ComplexRegionPlot[region[z], {z, 20}, PlotLabel -> z],
 ComplexRegionPlot[region[InverseFunction[g][z]], {z, 20}, 
  PlotLabel -> g[z]]}
```

then I get the desired result:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is because my function `f[z_] := z^(1/2)` is not the principal square root function but instead is giving both square roots. I will edit my original post accordingly.

Comment: The image (Image) of this this domain form can also be studied with geogabra: have a look there too. 
https://www.geogebra.org/m/gt6YKZnh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> …it appears that my function `f[z_] := z^(1/2)` is not the principal square root function.

No, actually it's the `InverseFunction` that's not calculating the inverse function in a mathematically rigorous manner. As mentioned in **Possible Issues** section of document of `InverseFunction`:

> Equations $f^{(-1)} (f (x))=x$ and $f\left(f^{(-1)}(y)\right)=y$ may not hold for arbitrary $x$ and $y$.

If you use `Solve` to calculate the inverse, a warning pops up (at least since *v12.3.1*):

```
Solve[f[z] == w, z]
```

> Solve::nongen: Solutions may not be valid for all values of parameters.

To calculate the inverse function rigorously, let's add a constraint to `Solve`:

```
fz = z /. First@Solve[{f[z] == w, Im[z] > 0}, z]
(* ConditionalExpression[w^2, Re[w] > 0 && Im[w] > 0] *)

ComplexRegionPlot[region[fz], {w, 20}, PlotLabel -> f[z], PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nicely done. I think it's noteworthy that while [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) complains in`V13`, in `V12` it does not.

Comment: @bmf Oh, didn't notice it's a new feature. The warning is already in _v12.3.1_.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about this :)

Comment: @xzczd thank you very much for this and apologies for taking so long to get back to it. this will definitely help me going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Using package :

```
Needs["Graphics`ComplexMap`"]
```

can be used
[Which replacement commands to find for CartesianMap and PolarMap?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263607/which-replacement-commands-to-find-for-cartesianmap-and-polarmap)

Comment: How can this package be used to solve OP's problem? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I read here for linear mapping : The transformation w = f(z) = z^(1/2) usually maps vertical and horizontal lines onto portions of hyperbolas. I have a few plot examples of linear mappping here that use the package Needs["GraphicsComplexMap`"] How to solve this issue takes some time....